# Correct way to deep copy std::string to char*

Tags: c++, string, dll

Which solution should I use to deep copy some content of a std::string to a char* over dll boundaries in C++?

- `memcpy(szValue, value.c_str(), value.size())`

or

- `strncpy_s(szValue, strlen(szValue), value.c_str(), value.length())`

Method in dll to call from outside:

```
unsigned int Interface::GetProp(const char* const szName, char* szValue)
{
    // ...

}
```

I tried it also with:

```
std::string value = m_xmlParser.GetNodeValue(propName);
std::vector<char> propValue(value.begin(), value.end());
propValue.push_back('\0');
szValue = &propValue[0];
```

but this is only a shallow copy (after leaving the dll the char* array is empty)

memcpy and strncpy_s are not C++ functions, but it is OK to use it here?

Thx

Comment: Why not a simple and plain [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcpy)?

Comment: It's not very clear what you want, what is `GetProp` supposed to do with the two parameters? Who is doing the copying? Why do you need a copy?

Comment: @user657267 Read my question! It's a dll and therefore I need a deep copy of the string! (forget the name of the method -> it doesn't matter)

Comment: the c++ versions of `memcpy` and `strncpy` are in the `cstring` library. so it is okay to use them in c++

Comment: @leon22 So your question is actually "How do I copy a `std::string` to an array of `char`s?" What the function does matters *greatly*, as the correct answer depends on who manages the lifetime of the character string.

Comment: By the way, your `memcpy` call doesn't create a C-style string in `szValue`. And your `strncpy_s` might actually give you undefined behavior.

Comment: Remember to add the terminator if you are copying to a char* otherwise all further strlen may fail.

Comment: @leon22 Your last suggestion _is_ a deep copy.  You're problem is elsewhere, probably with the lifetime of the copy, as others have suggested.

Comment: `szValue = .....` is no good, as `szValue` is local to this function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've got it correctly you are trying to implement GetProp this way:

```
unsigned int Interface::GetProp(const char* const szName, char* szValue)
{
    std::string value = m_xmlParser.GetNodeValue(propName);
    std::vector<char> propValue(value.begin(), value.end()); //propValue is on stack, mistake 1
    propValue.push_back('\0');
    szValue = &propValue[0]; 
}
```

On this line `szValue = &propValue[0];` you are making the szValue to point to the memory that will be deleted when the function will return - mistake 2, and the biggest mistake(3) of all is that you are modifying a local variable - szValue pointer to char is local...

```
unsigned int Interface::GetProp(const char* const szName, char* szValue)
{
    std::string value = m_xmlParser.GetNodeValue(propName);
    memcpy(szValue, value.c_str(), value.length()+1);
    return ... whatever you want to ...
}
```

How to call GetProp:

```
char buffer[MAX_SIZE_AS_PER_INTERFACE_API];
GetProp(propName, buffer);
```

Comment: Thx! I know there are issues with the vector approach! The question was only how to implement it correctly and safe! thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned int Interface::GetProp(const char* const szName, char* szValue)
```

The above function can only be meant to be called with an `szValue` argument pointing to a character buffer of some Interface API specified maximumn size.  There's no way to know what that size is from just looking at the function... you should check the documentation as hopefully there's a constant defined somewhere.  The correct way to call it would appear to be:

```
char buffer[MAX_SIZE_AS_PER_INTERFACE_API];
unsigned n = m_xmlParser.GetProp(propName, buffer);
```

It's also possible that there's a separate function to find out the length of the property value so you can create a known-large-enough buffer beforehand....

In the code above, `propName` could be a string literal, or `propName.c_str()` for a `std::string`.

You should also check the API to see what the returned `unsigned` value means.